# How a keyboard extension know it's running in a iPhone app on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

When using iPhone app on a iPad, the keyboard extension can only know the screen size of an iPad, but actually I should know it's like running on an iPhone, and get a size like an iPhone.

My current code runs in a iPhone app on iPad look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidAppear` of `UIInputViewController`, I can actually get the frame of `self.inputView`, that is 320 in this case.

However, `self.view` and `self.inputView`'s frame are both `CGRecteZero` in `viewDidload` or `viewWillAppear`, and that's actually why we should set keyboard height only after `[super viewDidAppear]`.

Comment: I definitely haven't done anything with creating custom extensions, but I'm curious to know if you can't just set the frame's width of the keyboard to self.view.frame.size.width, and add the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth autoresizingMask? With any normal subview, that will handle resizing it to the width of the view without needing to actually test for the value..

Comment: @Mike Yes, your are right, but because of some reasons we are still manually calculating the size.

Answer (score 0):

The actual size of the keyboard view(self.view.frame) can be checked right after invoking [super viewDidLayoutSubviews] in viewDidLayoutSubviews of UIInputViewController. It is the 1st place to check the size and much faster than viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Your Keyboard extension should be universal, if so then you can get device type (iPhone/iPad) by using below code.

```
let isPad = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
```

It may possible that you are using below method to get screen bounds

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
```

This method gives device's whole height, width in keyboard extension.

You can use nested condition by using above two condition to solve your problem.